# Sort dictionary by integers of missing dictionary keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key

I have a dict like this:

```
listofvirtues={1: 'Flexibility', 2: 'Authenticity', 4: 'Idealism', 5: 'Compassion', 8:'Consideration'}
```

but I want to get this result:

```
{1: 'Flexibility', 2: 'Authenticity', 3: 'Idealism', 4: 'Compassion', 5:'Consideration'}
```

How can I order the int keys if is not exists?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but if you want to have dictionary with keys like 1, 2, ... and values in the same order as in original int-keyed dict, then I believe it could look like this:

```
result = {i+1: listofvirtues[k] for i, k in enumerate(sorted(listofvirtues.keys()))}
```

Comment: Thanks Matmozaur! That's perfect!